# Laravel checkbox component unexpected end of file

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel 10 project and have created a checkbox component. I need to dynamically render the `checked` attribute to check the checkbox, else, render a default value. What am I missing to resolve the following error. Here's my component:

> syntax error, unexpected token "endif", expecting end of file

```html
<div>
  <x-checkbox-input id="is_enabled" name="is_enabled" value="1" {{ old('is_enabled') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
    <label for="is_enabled" class="font-medium text-gray-900">Enabled</label>
    <p class="text-gray-500">Toggle the enabled state</p>
  </x-checkbox-input>
  <x-input-error class="mt-2" :messages="$errors->get('is_enabled')" />
</div>
```

And the contents of that

```html
@props(['disabled' => false, 'checked' => false])

<div class="relative flex gap-x-3">
  <div class="flex h-6 items-center">
    <input {{ $disabled ? 'disabled' : '' }} {{ $checked ? 'checked' : '' }} {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'h-4 w-4 rounded border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-600']) }} type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div class="text-sm leading-6">
    {{ $slot }}
  </div>
</div>
```

It would seem that when I remove `{{ old('is_enabled') ? 'checked' : '' }}` the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to define or add a checked variable in the components, as $attributes->merge() will take care of it. You only need to define checked in the view like this: :checked="old('is_enabled')".

Here is the working code:

```
<div>
    <x-checkbox-input id="is_enabled" name="is_enabled" value="1" :checked="old('is_enabled')">
        <label for="is_enabled" class="font-medium text-gray-900">Enabled</label>
        <p class="text-gray-500">Toggle the enabled state</p>
    </x-checkbox-input>
    <x-input-error class="mt-2" :messages="$errors->get('is_enabled')" />
</div>
```

Component:

```
@props(['disabled' => false])

<div class="relative flex gap-x-3">
    <div class="flex items-center h-6">
        <input {{ $disabled ? 'disabled' : '' }} {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'h-4 w-4 rounded border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-600']) }} type="checkbox">
    </div>
    <div class="text-sm leading-6">
        {{ $slot }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, but my checkbox doesn't show as checked despite my value is my database being "1". Note, I am casting `is_enabled` to `boolean` at the model level

Comment: :checked="old('is_enabled')" does not retrieve the value from the database. Instead, it only displays the input value that was selected if a form is submitted but fails for one reason or another and redirects back to the page. "old('is_enabled')" ensures that the value selected by the user remains present.

Comment: You can learn more about Laravel CRUD from https://bootcamp.laravel.com/blade/editing-chirps

Comment: Thanks. I know how CRUD works. My CRUD setup is already done. Nothing on that page you linked references "checkbox". For clarity, my question is regarding the checkbox.